# What does it mean to type the "at" symbol in `C-c @ C-h`?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, help, prefix-keys

I'm using hideshow and I like it. The package is recommending me that I use the keys `C-c @ C-h` to hide a block instead of typing some really long command. I'm familiar with `C-c` and with `C-h`, but I can't figure out what the `@` means.

Comment: Following up on this question, is there any way to change the sequence of keys to something simpler? Like Tab and Shift Tab ? I find this sequence to be too long when working with org files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` doesn't mean anything, by itself, beside representing the `@` key on your keyboard.

The key sequence `C-c @ C-h` is bound to command `hs-hide-block` in `hs-minor-mode`, that is, in keymap `hs-minor-mode-map`.

- In that key sequence, `C-c` is a *prefix key*, which means it's bound to a *keymap*.
- In that keymap, `@` is a *prefix key*, which means it's bound to a *keymap*.
- In that keymap, `C-h` is bound to *command* `hs-hide-block`

---

In `hs-minor-mode`, type `C-c C-h` to see the key bindings on prefix key `C-c`.

Conventionally, typing `C-h` after a prefix key shows you all of the keys on that prefix key.  Prefix key `C-c @` disobeys this convention, so `C-c @ C-h` does **not** show you all the keys on prefix key `C-c @`. Instead, it gives you `hs-hide-block`.

(IMHO, that's unfortunate, but presumably the author thought otherwise.)

Comment: You can use `C-c @ <f1>` to show all keys on prefix key `C-c @`.

Comment: @npostavs: Yes. Good point. (IMHO, it's still too bad to not support the convention also with `C-h`.)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm familiar with C-c and with C-h, but I can't figure out what the @ means.

It's the literal character `@` for which your keyboard should have a key (or key sequence).  On my keyboard <kbd>@</kbd> is <kbd>Shift+2</kbd>.

So just type <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and then type <kbd>@</kbd>

Conceptually it's no different to being told to type `C-c a` (for example).