# How to list all the keybindings with the same prefix key?

Tags: key-bindings, help

How to list all keybindings that have same prefix?

For example, `M-g M-g` is bound to `goto-line`.

How to list all the keybindings that have the prefix `M-g`?

Comment: `M-g C-h` should do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330510/show-emacs-keybindings-which-start-with-a-particular-key

Comment: @NickD's answer is better than mine.

Comment: @NickD: Please post your comment as an answer, if you don't find a duplicate question.  The Q & A is useful.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53776/what-does-it-mean-to-type-the-at-symbol-in-c-c-c-h/53777#53777 @Drew provides an answer that answers this question as well.

Answer (score 3):

`M-g C-h` or `M-g F1` should do it. In general, pressing the prefix and then pressing `C-h` or `F1` should give you the keymap at that level - and it works with multi-level keymaps as well.

For a complete explanation, look in the [SO answer that @phils posted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330564/2561714).

See also [@Drew's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53776/what-does-it-mean-to-type-the-at-symbol-in-c-c-c-h/53777#53777) to a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

`describe-bindings` takes an optional argument PREFIX:

> The optional argument PREFIX, if non-nil, should be a key sequence;
> then we display only bindings that start with that prefix.

Thus evaluating

```
(describe-bindings (kbd  "M-g"))
```

does the job.

Answer (score 2):

I also enjoy the help the [which-key](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key) minor mode offers; it saves a couple of keystrokes to find out the 'rest' of the key binding mappings.

Answer (score 2):

Besides just `M-g C-h`, which @NickD mentioned, you can use library [Key See](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeySee).

Turn on minor mode `kc-mode` to enable completion on demand whenever you hit `S-TAB`, for keys and menu-bar menus.  So `M-g S-TAB` shows you what `M-g C-h` shows you: the keys you can use after `M-g`.  But you can also invoke one of them, by choosing it.  (`C-g` to cancel without invoking any command).